# sql: join and view

Tags: sql, select, join, view

I do i use join between multiple tables to expose a view

I have a main table that represents a list of hotels

```
Hotels( id_hotel, name,address, website)
```

Then I have another table that represents the coordinates of the hotel

```
hotel_coordinates(id_hotel,latitude,longidute)
```

And at the other end of a table that represents the picture associated with the hotel :

```
hotel_images(hotel_id,image)
```

The first table contains as many records as are hotels , that is, if there are 100 hotels in the table has 100 records

The second table contains a variable number of records , this number depends on the user for which he entered the coordinates of the hotel, for example may have 50 records . Each record is uniquely identified by id_hotel

The third table instead, as the second table can have a variable number of records as a function of the photos have been uploaded , otherwise this table for each id_hotel can have a number of records as a function of the photo , that is, for example,

the first hotel has 2 photos that have been uploaded will these 2 records :

```
     id_hotel  imageSize 1    imageSize2      imageSize3
      1        image1.jpeg     null            null
      1        image2          image3.jpeg     null
```

I would like to create a view that must have 100 records because 100 is the number of the hotel, then every field must be set opportunely (eg: if there is image1 then it must be appreciated , but if there is foto_1 the field must be set to null) . The columns of the view would be:

id_hotel; name; address; website; latitude; longitude; fhoto_1; fhoto_2; fhoto_3;

How can I use a join to have a view that shows 100 records? And set to null or valued the latitude longitude fhoto_1 fhoto_2 fhoto_3?

Comment: consider giving some sample data from the tables and expected resultset of the view.

Comment: it might just be that all you need is a left join

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? You are looking for a feature called "pivot", but that is *highly* DBMS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this would probably be better set up like this...

```
Hotel
---------
(PK) Id
Name
Address
Website

HotelLocation
--------------
(PK) Id
(FK) HotelId
Longitude
Latitude

Photo
-------
(PK) Id
Photo

HotelPhotos
------------
(PK) Id
(FK) HotelId
(FK) PhotoId
```

You could probably put the latitude and longitude in the Hotel table to make it easier, and just make the fields nullable when you create the table... like the following setup.

```
Hotel
---------
(PK) Id
Name
Address
Website
Latitude
Longitude

Photo
-------
(PK) Id
Photo

HotelPhotos
------------
(PK) Id
(FK) HotelId
(FK) PhotoId
```